# Using read.csv with a symlinked file

Tags: r, symlink, read.csv

**What I Am Trying To Do**

My source file is very large and I want to avoid copying it into other folders. I decided to create a symlink to the large file and want to use `read.csv` to read in the file.

Folder structure

- project1/data/source-file.csv
- project2/data/alias-to-source-file.csv

**What Went Wrong**

Reading in the source file works perfectly, but when I try to read in the symlink, I get the following error: `line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls`.

I know that I can just duplicate the file and put it into my second project's folder, but I want to know if there is a way to use symlinks. If not, I would like to know of a good way to avoid duplicating data files across many projects.

Comment: Symlinks should work. What operating system is this? Sure you made the symlink correctly? Is it really pointing to the right place?

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for an Rstudio friendly way, yes? I'm not an Rstudio guru, but maybe you could clarify why you can't just put the data file in another folder and use read.csv to read from the same file from within both projects.

Comment: I was creating aliases with a OS X via the GUI. I just tried using `ln -s` via commandline, and I get the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Symlinks work when made correctly on my system.

```
> read.csv("foo.csv")
  X1 X2 X3
1  3  4  5
2  5  6  7
> system("ln -s foo.csv bar.csv")
> read.csv("bar.csv")
  X1 X2 X3
1  3  4  5
2  5  6  7
```

Bad symlinks can produce errors, but I can't replicate your error:

Symlink to non-existent file:

```
> system("ln -s nonsuch.csv baz.csv")
> read.csv("baz.csv")
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'baz.csv': No such file or directory
```

Link to existent directory folder:

```
> system("ln -s / qux.csv")
> read.csv("qux.csv")
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

Comment: I was creating aliases with a OS X via the GUI. I just tried using `ln -s` via commandline, and I get the same issue. But you have given me enough info to know that the symlink is causing the issue. I will investigate further! Thanks!

Comment: I can imagine aliases not working because they are just files with metadata for the target, and do contain a lot of null bytes which might explain the "null" part of your error. But I'm no OSX expert and have asked for more help here for you...