# Reading data through symlink in R

Tags: r, macos, symlink

I have a problem reading symlinks that point to data files in R, using macOS. I barely know the basics of Unix shell, so maybe I'm missing something about the way it works.

I have a folder structure like this one:

```
- project
  |--- task1
  |     |-- task1.R
  |     |-- output
  |           |-- data.csv
  |
  |--- task2
        |-- task2.R
        |-- input
```

And using I just create a symlink in `task2` that points to `task1/output/data.csv`:

```
ln -s task1/output/data.csv task2/input/
```

But when I try to load it in R, it doesn't work:

```
> setwd("..../project")
> data = read.csv("task2/input/data.csv")

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'task2/input/data.csv': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to use symlinks to load data in R? In this case, I know it would be much simpler to just read it directly from the original folder, but I'm trying to come up a solution to multiple projects that use the same data files without having duplicated files in the computer, and also learn how this works.

Thank you.

Comment: They should work, try the example from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39128617/680068

Comment: Just found out a solution, but don't really know why it works. So if I create the symlink using the full path to the original file, it works:```ln -s /Users/username/Documents/project/task1/output/data.csv task2/input/```

Comment: Great, of course it needs full path, feel free post your comment as answer below, and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution seems to be creating the symlink using the full path pointing to the original file, e.g.:

```
ln -s /Users/username/project/task1/output/data.csv task2/input/
```

Comment: I create my links in R (using fs package = `fs::create_link(p1, p2)`) so only need to expand path by: `fs::create_link(fs::path_real(p1), p2)`.

Comment: Rather than having the full name to the original data, I prefer having a relative path.  In your example, you would run `cd task2/input/ && ln -s ../../task1/output/data.csv ./`.  That way, no matter what computer you run your project on, as long as the project structure stays the same, the symbolic link will work.